# Java Log4j2 Syslog Appender

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j2

I'm trying to use Log4j 2.6.1 in order to sent log messages via Syslog.
I'm able to print them to file or console but I cannot seem to catch them in my Syslog server,or verify that they're even being sent.

The configuration file I'm using is based on one I've found online, I'm not sure if I need to use BSD Syslog format or the RFC 5424.

I'm running on Windows server (the Syslog server is located on the same machine).

**Here's my configuration file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <Appenders>
    <Syslog name="syslogAppender" format="RFC5424" host="localhost" newLine="true" port="514" protocol="UDP" appName="MyApp" 
        facility="USER" messageId="Audit" mdcId="mdc" id="App"
        connectTimeoutMillis="1000" reconnectionDelayMillis="5000"/>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.mycorp" level="info" />
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="syslogAppender"/>
        </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**Here is the class:**

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class SyslogLogger
{
    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(SyslogLogger.class);

    public static void main (String[] args)throws IOException,SQLException
    {
        LOG.error("testing ERROR level");
        LOG.trace("exiting application");
    }
}
```

Please advise what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend raising a ticket on the Log4j 2 Jira issue tracker for this. You may have found a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, But I solved it by considering following points:

1. add a "\0" to end of each log message, but it is completely related to my log server, server use eliminator for messages.
2. add property    "includeMDC"="true" for syslog appender properties

so syslog appender work correctly and you should check following possibilities:

1. syslog server configuration(such as foramt, protocol, MDC and ...)
2. revise your syslog appender properties based on server input format